# mysql_connect can not work in remote server in stead of local server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got such warning :

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50537 Library:50617
```

when try to upload my code to my remote server, and my remote server currently using php 5.5
, It's because the mysql extension has been already deprecated so that i have to change the extension to mysqli?
but in my local server, i tested in php 5.5 too and it works as normal

what would be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running ubuntu/debian.

```
     apt-cache search php5-mysqlnd
```

Find one that fits:

```
     apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: yum install php-mysqlnd

Comment: Can't do cli from WHM. You need to connect to your server via SSH & type: yum update && yum install php-mysqlnd

Comment: I see, i need to run a putty like application and get connection with my server trhtough SSH, and then insatll it?

Comment: Yes, you can use any SSH client out there, the same way you installed WHM.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is [this](http://www.dotdeb.org/2014/04/04/about-the-mysql_connect-headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch-warning-2/):

> After having MySQL 5.6.17 published, some users complained about a
>   warning thrown by their PHP applications :
>
> PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version
>   mismatch. Headers:50535 Library:50617
>
> In fact, this could happen with any application linked to
>   libmysqlclient18 in a certain version (php5-mysql from Dotdeb is
>   linked to the 5.5.35 version from the stock Debian distribution) when
>   connecting to a MySQL server in another version (5.6.17 in our case).
>   The warning is thrown by libmysqlclient18 itself. And this is just a
>   warning, there is no reason why any bad behavior would happen in that
>   case.
>
> Of course, I could build php5-mysql against the latest
>   libmysqlclient18 (5.6.17), but it would lead to very bad issues, such
>   as duplicate symbols or segfaults when PHP is loaded with other
>   MySQL-linked modules from the stock Debian distribution (those are
>   linked to libmysqlclient18 5.5.35). For example : mod_php5 + Apache +
>   mod_auth_mysql would crash.
>
> If this this warning really annoys you, feel free to install
>   php5-mysqlnd instead of php5-mysql :
>
> ```
> it’s a drop-in replacement
> it’s not linked against any libmysqlclient library
> it won’t throw any irrelevant warning about version mismatch
> it has a lot of benefits. See http://www.php.net/mysqlnd for more info
> ```
>
> I hope this helps.